# Podman on Mac throws error when running podman machine init

Tags: macos, homebrew, podman

Installed podman using brew (`brew install podman`)
Trying to start the VM using `podman machine init` but receiving the following error:

```
Extracting compressed file
Error: cannot overwrite connection
```

Info:

````
$ podman machine ls
NAME        VM TYPE     CREATED     LAST UP     CPUS        MEMORY      DISK SIZE```
````

```
$ brew info podman
podman: stable 4.1.0 (bottled), HEAD
Tool for managing OCI containers and pods
https://podman.io/
/usr/local/Cellar/podman/4.1.0 (174 files, 48.2MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2022-06-09 at 15:49:37
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/podman.rb
License: Apache-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: go ✘, go-md2man ✘
Required: qemu ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
zsh completions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Analytics
install: 19,856 (30 days), 60,723 (90 days), 152,955 (365 days)
install-on-request: 19,746 (30 days), 60,606 (90 days), 152,824 (365 days)
build-error: 1 (30 days)
```

```
sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.6.6
BuildVersion:   20G624
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled using brew, does not change.
Had docker on machine, uninstalled it completely, restarted my machine and tried again reinstalling podman with brew. The problem remains.

Any pointers, instructions how to resolve it appreciated greatly. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resolved the issue by following these steps:

1. Removed podman `brew uninstall podman`
2. Removed containers files from the following directories:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/containers/
rm -rf ~/.local/share/containers
```

3. Reinstalled podman using brew `brew install podman`
4. Init the podman machine and start it.

Comment: You may also need to remove the ssh-keys as seen in a different answer.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @Simas Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72571826/3596851

After removing the container files

```
rm -rf ~/.config/containers/
rm -rf ~/.local/share/containers
```

I had to remove additional Podman related files:

```
rm ~/.ssh/podman*
```

Then I reinstalled Podman `brew install podman`, followed by init `podman machine init`, and `podman machine start`. This worked for me

Answer (score 3):

```
podman machine stop
podman machine rm
podman machine init
podman machine start
```

These steps work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error using `podman machine init` on Windows 10. Following @Simas solution worked, on Windows 10 the folders are in the user directory:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\.config\containers
C:\Users\<USER>\.local\share\containers
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).