# unable to start podman 4.3.1 on Mac

Tags: podman

Using podman 4.3.1, I get these errors:

```
$ podman machine start
Starting machine "podman-machine-default"
Waiting for VM ...
Error: EOF

$ podman machine stop 
Error: EOF
$
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you solve it? Sometimes everything is working fine... sometimes not. Rebooting may help.

Comment: @ThomasRamé unfortunately the issue is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you can remove the current podman machine and then initialise a new one with:

```
podman machine rm
podman machine init
```

https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine-rm.1.html
https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine-init.1.html

Comment: I've tried all sort of removing and recreating the machine, didn't help. This happened after upgrading the podman desktop.

Comment: Ah can you share more information? e.g. your system and how you installed and updated podman?

Comment: I'm trying this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562644/podman-on-mac-throws-error-when-running-podman-machine-init) and will update if it resolves my issue.